# Why cant we use setOnClickListener and onClick Attribute of XML at the same time

Tags: android

I have set the onClicklistner

```
resend.setEnabled(false);  // button property
//resend.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
resend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        resend(v);
        //Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, " Button is Enable ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

its resend method just to go for another activity

```
public void resend (View v) {
    StartActivity.this.finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

here goes xml part

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnResend"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="resend"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="Resend"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

why cant i have both  onClick Attribute  of XML and  setOnClickListener when defined in xml the setOnClickListener doesnt work ??

Comment: Is there any way to get both things done.I am new can anybody help me for using both at the same time.

Comment: Short answer -> No

Answer (score 2):

When setting the `android:onClick` attribute the `View` internally sets an `OnClickListener` with `setOnClickListener()` within the constructor.

So both are mutually exclusive.

Comment: sounds reasonable

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need both. But maybe `view.performClick()` can help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one View.OnClickListener variable inside the View class, so you can only create a single OnClickListener, it might be from XML or from java side, does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

May be you forget relation from xml to java code.
Add `tools:context=`"{absolute path java file container event click}".